# JavaFX background-image scaling

Tags: java, css, javafx, background-image, javafx-css

I have this piece of code, which works fine.

```
gamePane.setPrefSize(game.getMaxX(), game.getMaxY());
```

However, the background-image my `gamePane` (which is a `Pane`) has automatically scales with it, and I do not want this. I've searched for background scaling properties, but I couldn't find anything.
The image is originally applied with css.

Edit: I have found the solution!

What my css code was originally:

```
.background {
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/background.png");
}
```

What I made it to be:

```
.background {
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/background.png");
    -fx-background-size: 1024 768;
    -fx-background-position: center;
}
```